# Como fazer uma contagem de argumentos repetidos em R

Tags: array, r, matriz, argumento, planilha

tenho uma planilha, tenho que fazer algumas operações nos dados, entao exportei para o R e consegue selecionar os argumentos importante, agora preciso saber quantos elementos repetidos existem em uma coluna:
por Exemplo

PRTR4: 4
VALE5: 20
.
.
.

como posso fazer essa contagem?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow português! Infelizmente fica difícil ajudar com pouca informação. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/80049) e então edite sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dê uma olhada na função `table`. Mas do mais, seria interessante você aprimorar sua pergunta, disponibilizando seu conjunto de dados, ou uma parte dele (função `dput`).

```
table(ColunadeInteresse)
```

Comment: Obrigado, infelizmente não posso compartilhar os dados, mas deu super certo essa funcao Table, muito obrigado mesmo.